# React Native - unexpected rendering of component

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I am rendering a `ListView` in a React Native app that I'm building and am finding that a parent `View` container for the row is not expanding to fit all the content within it and I'm not sure why.

See in screenshot below how the second row within the row is rendered within the margin of the row `view`:

[image]

Component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'native-base';

const ListViewRow = (props) => {
  const { booking } = props;
  const guest = props.guests[booking.guest_id];

  return (
    <View style={styles.rowStyle}>
      <View style={styles.leftContentStyle}>
        <View>
          <Text>{guest.fullname}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>{booking.start_date} - {booking.end_date}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rightContentStyle}>
        <Icon name='ios-arrow-forward' />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  rowStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  leftContentStyle: {
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  rightContentStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { guests: state.guests };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListViewRow);
```